# Manually Set ModelState.isValid from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Is there a way for me to manually set the `ModelState.isValid = False` from the controller?

I have some code like this

```
    Dim _region As Domain.Region = RegionService.GetRegionByNameAndParentID(user.UserRegion, user.ParentRegionID)
    If ModelState.IsValid AndAlso Not _region Is Nothing Then
           ''# ...
    Else
           Return View(user)
    End If
```

But if _region is nothing, then I don't get any Validation Errors firing.

I thought about implementing a custom validator, but it would require hitting the database twice (once for validation and once to set the value).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can't set `ModelState.IsValid` directly, as it's a derived property that simply checks the models error collection. You can however add your own model errors, e.g:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Region", "Region is mandatory");
```

`ModelState.IsValid` will then return false.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you cannot set the Modelstate directly, but sometimes it is useful to clear it and that is very well possible:

```
  ModelState.Clear();
```

Will reset the ModelState.