# validation - user has already been added, MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

Am trying to add validation to my code.

When i enter a username , and try it again i get an error saying Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

As i have 2 primary key (serialnumber and productNumber) so i wont able to add a user 2nd time, but when i do, i get an error page.

But really i would want a message saying a user has already been added or something in that line.

Iv tried goggling answers but being going around in circles, so thought il ask you guys.

This is my code

Model:

```
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Before you submit you must enter a valid UserName!")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [Display(Name = "Alternative Username")]
    public string AltUserName { get; set; }

    public ReadingsUsersForm(string Ser_Num)
    {
        SerialNumber = Ser_Num;
        ProductNumber = cpctx.CustomerReadingsEntries.Where(s => s.ser_num == SerialNumber).Select(c => c.prod_um).FirstOrDefault();
        UserName = null;
        AltUserName = null;  
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(EntrtyForm form)
    {

        var addForm = new M2CPDAL.Models.CustomerPortal.SerialUser();
        addForm.ser_num = form.SerialNumber;
        addForm.prod_num = form.ProductNumber;

        addForm.UserName = form.UserName;
        addForm.AltUserName = form.AltUserName;
        cp.SerialUsers.Add(addForm);
        cp.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }   

        public PartialViewResult GetAddEditReadings(string ser_num, string prod_num)
    {
        var model = new  AddEditReadingsViewModel(id, ser_num, prod_num, uProfile.CustNums);

        return PartialView("_ReadingsUsers", model);
    }
```

html code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Device", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

{

<fieldset>
    <legend>Meter Reading Details</legend>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SerialNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SerialNumber, new { @class = "form", @readonly = "readonly" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SerialNumber)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductNumber, new { @class = "form", @readonly = "readonly" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProductNumber)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @id = "newColourReading", @class = "form-add" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        <div id="ColourErrorMessage"></div>
   </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AltUserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AltUserName, new { @id = "newColourReading", @class = "form-add2" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AltUserName)
        <div id="ColourErrorMessage"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" id="ButtonSave" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

}

```
etc...
```

So in the cp.SaveChanges(); i will get an error if i tried adding an user for the 2nd time.

Any ideas or direction i can follow where i can add an validation to check if this has already been added or not.

Comment: Call the database to check the values are unique, and if not, use `ModelState.AddModelError()` to add an error and then return the view to display it. You could also use a `[Remote]` attribute to perform the validation on the client before you submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve it using standard Validation Attributes. You should get the answer from your DB. Here if one way how you can imlement it in your solution.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(EntrtyForm form)
{

    var addForm = new M2CPDAL.Models.CustomerPortal.SerialUser();
    var serialUser = cp.SerialUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.serialNumber == form.serialNumber && x.productNumber == form.productNumber);
    if(serialUser == null)
    {
      addForm.ser_num = form.SerialNumber;
      addForm.prod_num = form.ProductNumber;
      addForm.UserName = form.UserName;
      addForm.AltUserName = form.AltUserName;
      cp.SerialUsers.Add(addForm);
      cp.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("serialUserExist");
}
```

But better solution if you have strongly typed View using `ModelState.IsValid`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(EntrtyForm form)
{

    var addForm = new M2CPDAL.Models.CustomerPortal.SerialUser();
    var serialUser = cp.SerialUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.serialNumber == form.serialNumber && x.productNumber == form.productNumber);
    if(serialUser == null)
    {
      addForm.ser_num = form.SerialNumber;
      addForm.prod_num = form.ProductNumber;
      addForm.UserName = form.UserName;
      addForm.AltUserName = form.AltUserName;
      cp.SerialUsers.Add(addForm);
      cp.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("SerialNumber", "Already Exist");
    var model = new AddEditReadingsViewModel(form);
    return PartialView("_ReadingsUsers", form);
}
```

Don't forget to create constructor that init `AddEditReadingsViewModel` from your `EntrtyForm`

Comment: thanks i get this, but am getting an error on ModelState.IsValid = property or indexer 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary.IsValid' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Ooops, my bad. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3169667/1849444) is explanation.

Comment: ok cool thanks, but you no where you have     return View("AddSerialUserView"); is this suppose to return a new page or something, because all i want is a error message...

Comment: If you want just error message - yes you can just return another View and pass string with Error.

Comment: Can you show me controller method from where you get your form and whole View in question? Just to make more clear what is your situation.

Comment: If you use`ModelState.AddModelError("SerialNumber", "Already Exist")` and then you need to return the same view with `return View(form);`

Comment: the problem is the return view. i dont want it to return any view, i just want an error to say it already exist. all the code in the question.... the return view is directing it to another page...

Comment: Tou don't get it. You should place there your **register new user** view as @StephenMuecke say.

Comment: what do you mean by register new user

Comment: That's why i asked you to place in question your get form controller method. Not post method that you have already. And view

Comment: updated the code. bare in mind theeres alot of stuff going on, so i wanted to try keeping it as simple as possible. so how would i just add an error message rather than return to another page.

Comment: `var model = new  AddEditReadingsViewModel(form);
return PartialView("_ReadingsUsers", model);`

But i see it is partial View so if it is in modal dialog you probably should use `Ajax.BeginForm` Instead of `Html.BeginForm` on your View.

Comment: no its not doing it, its giving me error, all i only want is a red error message, not to return to a diffrent page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66207/discussion-between-teo-van-kot-and-m-ali).

Answer (score 1):

in your Save method, just put some code that looks for and entry with this serialnumber and product number already. If there, send the user to another page

```
var exist = cp.SerialUsers.Where(x => x.serialNumber == form.serialNumber && x.productNumber == form.productNumber).FirstOrDefault()
if(exist!=null)
    return RedirectToAction("Exists");
```