# How to set model state to valid when file input gets null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When i try to create new record without choosing any file its is gives me
**The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase' failed because no type converter can convert between these types**  error. i want to create record with or without file choosing from the user. if HttpPostedFileBase[] null Model State Should be valid. I have check there is no Required validation for the HttpPostedFileBase in the model also.

```
[HttpPost]        
        public ActionResult NewTheme(ThemeModel themeModel, ColorItem colorItem, ImageItem imageItem, Dictionary<string, HttpPostedFileBase[]> selectedImageList)
        {
            try
            {               
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                }
              }
         }
```

I want to be able to ModelState valid when Dictionary **HttpPostedFileBase** gets null also

Comment: How do we reproduce this?

Comment: @John issue is model state is not valid when i'm not choosing file input then DIctionary HttpPostedFileBase [] gets null. I want to be able to model state valid when httppostedfilebase gets null also

Comment: Can we see the model?

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: Please share the request you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `ModelState.IsValid` directly, as it's a derived property that simply checks the models error collection. You can however add your own model errors, e.g:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("selectedImageList", "File is mandatory");
```

ModelState.IsValid will then return false.

**From here:** [Manually Set ModelState.isValid from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169585/manually-set-modelstate-isvalid-from-controller)

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers. Vote to close the question as duplicate instead.

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.IsValid is an aggregation of each field validation. You can control each field validity individually.

One can **set a field to valid** with this two methods:

```
ModelState.ClearValidationState("Password");
ModelState.MarkFieldValid("Password");
```

Need to use both because the second one without the first one it gives an error stating that the state is already marked.

To **set a field to invalid**, just use ModelState.AddModelError() method